# wordpress search doesn't apply for my projects

Tags: php, wordpress, templates

I am using Thallasa theme from themeforest.net. It's kinda awful but nevermind, when i made a search and add my pages, posts, projects items (which are in a custom post type obviously) the search can't find the project items. It finds the projects page, every other page or post but not the single projects.

The website is http://sisgroup.webpandas.com/

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code to your functions.php (modify the post types to yours.

```
<?php

  function filter_search($query) {
    if ($query->is_search) {
      $query->set('post_type', array('post', 'page', 'projects'));
    }

    return $query;
   }

   add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'filter_search');

?>
```